# Reading file into a list

Tags: python, list, file-io

I need to read a list of values from an input file and converting it into a single-dimensional list. The input file contains a list of values, as shown below:

`my_non_ods_file`

```
sdsx

sds1

sds3

sds2
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is as follows:

```
valuelist = ['sdsx', 'sds1','sds2','sds3']
```

To accomplish this, I tried using the following code:

```
data_non_ods = my_non_ods_file.read()
valuelist.append(data_non_ods.replace('\n' ,'').split())
```

However, the output I received was:

```
valuelist = [['sdsx', 'sds1','sds2','sds3']]
```

How can I read the list into a single-dimensional list or convert the current output to a single-dimensional list?

Answer (score 1):

This should do:

```
valuelist = my_non_ods_file.read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
lines = [stripped for l in my_file if (stripped := l.strip())]
```

Example:

```
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO("""
sdsx

sds1

sds3

sds2
""")

# with open('/file') as f:
#     lines = [stripped for l in f if (stripped := l.strip())]

lines = [stripped for l in data if (stripped := l.strip())]
print(lines)
```

Out:

```
['sdsx', 'sds1', 'sds3', 'sds2']
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to keep in mind:

In your original approach, you first remove all the newline characters, I'm assuming you only get the result that you do because there's additional whitespace somewhere for `.split()` to split on.

Remember that `.split()` itself returns a list, and `.append()` takes in an element and adds it into the original list- so in your example, you had an empty list, and you're appending an entire list into it.

You could use the `my_file.open().splitlines()` as a one-liner, but that doesn't close the file descriptor. A better approach would be to use the context manager as such:

```py
with open(my_file_name) as f:
  data = f.splitlines()
```

This ensures that the file is closed.

Additional reading for `with` statement: [Original PEP](https://peps.python.org/pep-0343/#examples), [Context managers in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/context-manager-in-python/), [`open` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Thank you for making me understand why there is a 2 dimensional list is created